# Ruptured HTML tags in product description (Opencart 1.5.5.1)

Tags: php, opencart

I'm experiencing some troubles with the product description on the category page and would be grateful to get some hints.

Because all the text from the description merged in an ugly way, I made some changes in catalog/controller/product/category.php (and specials.php and search.php) to include HTML tags:

```
'description' => utf8_substr(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), 0, 100) . '..',
```

instead of

```
'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
```

At first, everything appeared the way I wanted it to be. 
But in one case the specified character limit exactly happens within an HTML tag, which causes the entire layout to crash. The description ended with " </ "

Of course, when changing the text length everything was fine again, but I hardly can ask my customer to count characters.

Is it possible to prevent breaks within HTML tags? 
Or is there a better way to handle formatting? Some recommendations for an extension maybe?

Thanks in advance,
Dagmar

Answer (score 0):

I placed the following method inside my Url class, then call it via:

`$this->url->truncate($description, 150);`

```
// truncate method
public function truncate ($string, $limit = 145, $break = ".", $pad = ".") {
    // return with no change if string is shorter than $limit
    if (strlen ($string) <= $limit) return $string;

    // is $break present between $limit and the end of the string?
    if (false !== ($breakpoint = strpos($string, $break, $limit))):
        if ($breakpoint < strlen($string) - 1):
            $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint) . $pad;
        endif;
    endif;

    return $string;
}
```

It will break only after a period AFTER the set limit.

Works pretty good.